# Unhandled HTTP request using @slack/bolt and ngrok

Tags: slack-api, slack-bolt

I created a Slack bot using @slack/bolt on Node.js. When I work in socket mode, everything works without problems. When I turn off socket mode and create a tunnel with ngrok, my actions stop running. Every time I click on the buttons in the views I created, I get the error message "Unhandled HTTP request (POST) made to /slack/actions".

I specified the URL of the Ngrok tunnel in the app configuration in the Interactivity and Shortcuts section, appending the path "slack/actions" to the end (by the way, I also tried not specifying the path and using the URL as is).

I tried to fix the error by adding a middleware that logs each request, but strangely, the events are logged but not the actions.

I'm at a loss for what to do. Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you go with the default settings, the path is /slack/events , not /slack/actions